# PHP: use one global file pointer in a static `log` method

Tags: php, logging, global-scope

I'd like to call a `log` method statically throughout my app:

```
App::log('Some message');
```

but then I'd like to create a file pointer only once, so that it's accessible from within that method(`$file_pointer`) each time it's called.

```
public static function log($message) {
  (...)
  fwrite($file_pointer, $processed_message);
}
```

Is there a design pattern or any other architectural solution that addresses this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an architectural solution, but you can use `file_put_contents()` in your log method to circumvent this:

```
file_put_contents($pathname, $output, FILE_APPEND);
```

This will append your message to the log file without the need to communicate a file resource, you only have to specify the pathname.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.